# Substituting Names in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, substitution

I am looking for the best away to transfer and change to name in a cell.

Example:
I have a table of acronyms such as: LRG, LAA, LBG
I want to create a function that lists the full names in a table next to it.

I want it it to read "LRG" and know to insert "Large" in the cell next two it. The table with the acronyms will change daily and I would like the corresponding full names to change with it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I tried to use the substitute function =substitute(B34, "LRG", "Large". However, as the acronym table will change I have to keep updating the names that I am substituting.

Comment: Idex() with match(), or vlookup() and a data table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have lookup table then could use `XLOOKUP()`.

```
=XLOOKUP(A2,D:D,E:E)
```

For dynamic array use `BYROW()` or `MAP()` function.

```
=BYROW(A2:A4,LAMBDA(x,XLOOKUP(x,D:D,E:E)))
```

[image]

Comment: @user21897381 Glad to know. It it helps then please consider accept the answer (tick mark it).